# more(1) writing to stdout without actually applying the pager

Tags: c, exec, system-calls, pager

I'm trying to create a C program that runs printenv | grep [parameters] | sort | more, and so far everything is working, and the program is printing the sorted environment variables to stdout as it's supposed to. The only problem is that there is no pager, even though the last process I'm starting - the only one with a file descriptor to stdout - is more. Here's the relevant code, I've tried editing out stuff that I know works.

```
#define PIPE_READ 0
#define PIPE_WRITE 1
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    int pipe_fd[3][2];
    pipe(pipe_fd[0]);
    pipe(pipe_fd[1]);
    pipe(pipe_fd[2]);

    pid[0]=fork();
    if(pid[0]==0)   /*grep-process*/
    {
        dup2(pipe_fd[0][PIPE_READ], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipe_fd[1][PIPE_WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
        /*close all 3 pipes, both ends, then execute grep*/
        argv[0]= "grep";
        execvp("grep",argv);
    }
    pid[1]=fork();
    if(pid[1]==0)   /*sort-process*/
    {
        dup2(pipe_fd[1][PIPE_READ], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipe_fd[2][PIPE_WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
        /*close all 3 pipes, both ends, then execute sort*/
        execlp("sort","sort", (char*) 0);
    }
    pid[2]=fork();
    if(pid[2]==0)   /*more-process*/
    {
        dup2(pipe_fd[2][PIPE_READ], STDIN_FILENO);
        /*close all 3 pipes, both ends, then execute more*/
        execlp("more","more", (char*) 0);
    }

    /*parent-process*/
    /*close all pipes except for the write end on the first, then write*/
       for(i=0; envp[i]!=NULL; i++)
   {
      write(pipe_fd[0][PIPE_WRITE],envp[i], strlen(envp[i]));
      write(pipe_fd[0][PIPE_WRITE],"\n",1);
   }
   close(pipe_fd[0][PIPE_WRITE]);
```

Of course I do check the return values of every call, and where I close all the pipes I simply wrote a comment to simplify reading it. 
A call to ./a.out PATH results in this:

```
INFOPATH=/usr/share/info
MANPATH=/usr/local/vol/matlab/7.4.0/man:/usr/kerberos/man:/usr/local/share/man:/
  usr/share/man/en:/usr/share/man:/usr/man
MANPATH=/usr/local/vol/matlab/7.4.0/man:/usr/kerberos/man:/usr/local/share/man:/
  usr/share/man/en:/usr/share/man:/usr/man
MODULEPATH=/usr/local/vol/modulefiles:/pkg/modules/modulefiles:/etc/site/modulef
  iles:/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles
MODULEPATH=/usr/local/vol/modulefiles:/pkg/modules/modulefiles:/etc/site/modulef
  iles:/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles
...
...
```